# How to connect to encrypted database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption, connection

Database shopdata.db is encrypted. How to use `SQLiteConnection` for this?

```
public SQLiteConnect()
{
    this.con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=shopdate.db;Password=123);
    this.cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
    this.cmd.Connection = this.con;
}
```

I want to get the data in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli), SQLite doesn't support encrypting database files by default. Instead, you need to use a modified version of SQLite like SEE, SQLCipher, SQLiteCrypt, or wxSQLite3.

Can you confirm what you are using?